# Fix Rails oauth facebook x-frame-options sameorigin error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, facebook-oauth

I can't for the life of me get my Facebook canvas app to display.  Chrome console displays this error and nothing shows up inside the iframe - it's blank:

`Refused to display 'http://mysite.dev/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

I'm using *Rails 4.0.0.rc1* and *omniauth-facebook 1.4.1*, following the [Railscast on Facebook Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360) as a guide.  I didn't use any of the Javascript code since it was optional and ideally the app should only be accessed within Facebook.

**routes.rb**

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post]
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout', via: [:get, :post]
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

**application_controller.rb**

I had to comment this out because I kept getting InvalidAuthenticityToken errors which cost me the other half of my day.  A bit more on that [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/237#issuecomment-908732).

```
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

**Facebook settings**

- App domain: `myapp.dev`
- Canvas URL: `http://myapp.dev`
- Secure Canvas URL: -- blank -- if https is specified, I get *webpage is unavailable*

Please help before I start flipping desks.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails 4, X-FRAME-OPTIONS is set to SAMEORIGIN in the headers, which I guess prevents it from being loaded in a frame, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6311).  One person notes [the difficulty this will cause Facebook app developers](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6311#issuecomment-5704078).

I managed to solve this by adding the following to `application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers[:'X-Frame-Options'] = "ALLOW-FROM https://apps.facebook.com"
```

I also used [Forward](http://forwardhq.com) to create a domain to allow Facebook to access my local development machine.  I entered this domain in the `canvas` and `secure canvas` fields in Facebook.  Highly recommended.

Further info here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: This actually resulted in another error: `Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://myapp.dev/': 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.`  Still trying to sort all of this out.

Comment: Did you find out a solution for the comment above ?

Comment: This actually worked.  The key is to get the header ignored because otherwise the page is blank.  Ultimately, I ended up using [Forward](http://forwardhq.com/) to get my app to work properly which I would recommend to anyone developing locally who values their sanity.

Comment: Correction.  This WAS working until today.  Now the headers are reading "SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com".  Urgghh..

Comment: The ALLOW-FROM value does matter - edited answer to be https://apps.facebook.com.

Comment: when making this change I also got an error that now there were multiple headers: SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM. The answer below: "config.action_dispatch.default_headers.clear" fixed that issue though I hope there is a better way without clearing them entirely

Comment: It looks like "Allow-FROM" is not supported in all browsers(particularly Chrome): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options.  I'm using the solution listed here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445782/how-to-override-x-frame-options-for-a-controller-or-action-in-rails-4) as an after-filter.  Allow-From will be ignored on browsers that don't support it but by setting it in the after filter, it will clear out the SAME-ORIGIN header thereby getting this to work. godspeed.

Answer (score 4):

I found this part of the edge guide, which explains Rails 4's default headers, to be useful:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#default-headers

Here is the main point, copied and pasted:

> #### Every HTTP response from your Rails application receives the following default security headers.
>
> config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {   'X-Frame-Options' =>
> 'SAMEORIGIN',   'X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block',
> 'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff' }
>
> #### You can configure defaultheaders in config/application.rb.
>
> config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {   'Header-Name' =>
> 'Header-Value',   'X-Frame-Options' => 'DENY' }
>
> #### Or you can remove them.
>
> config.action_dispatch.default_headers.clear