# Redirect in an IFrame

Tags: php, html, iframe

My company has a customer portal.  One of the features of the portal is a "Coupon" page which shows them various coupons that they can use to save money.

The Coupon page is provided by an outside vendor with whom we have contracted.  They require users to be logged in, and provide an API to register, and then log the person in.

I have tested the registration and Login process in a normal browser, and it works fine.

However, we now want to bring the site into our own portal, so that our customers have to log into our site in order to get to the coupon page.  So I put the vendor site inside an iframe of our portal so it appears that the vendor site is actually a part of our own site.

The coupon site then does show in the iframe.  However, the user is not logged in, even though the API is used to get the login token, and the token is then used in the iframe url.

When the site is accessed without an iframe with the same URL, the user is logged in correctly, and then there is a redirect to another page.

However, when it is accessed inside the iframe, the redirect occurs, but the user is not logged in.

In looking in Developer Tools, I see a PHPSESSID cookie being set in both the iframe, and when not in an iframe.  So it appears the token is being used successfully to log the person in and get the PHPSESSID.

So the question is why doesn't the user appear to be logged in when this is done in a iframe?

Maybe there is a cross origin header issue?

I am testing this in Chrome and Edge with the same result.

Comment: Are you, by chance, testing in safari? That browser [specifically blocks this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723056/safari-13-iframe-blocks-cors-cookies)

Comment: No, testing in Chrome.

Comment: There must be other cookie responsible for session of the application. Check the console output of Developer Tools. Look for "Cookie XXX rejected..." message.

Comment: @Malipek, thank you, you are correct.  Although it appeared to me at first that cookies were being set for the iframe, it turns out they are not getting set at all.  But that is a different issue.