# Rails 6. Allow the specific pages be embedded in iFrame by any other domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, ruby-on-rails-6, x-frame-options

I'd like to allow anyone to embed my Rails website via iFrame. But I want to open only some specific routes, like `/emded/entity1/:entity1_id` and `/emded/entity2/:entity2_id`.

For example, Youtube does that.
I can embed the following code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

But if I change the `src` attribute to just `https://www.youtube.com/`, this iframe won't display anything.

What is the way to do the same in Rails?

I've tried to follow this guide that I found for the Rails 4: http://jerodsanto.net/2013/12/rails-4-let-specific-actions-be-embedded-as-iframes/

I've created a method in Application Controller:

```
  def allow_iframe
    response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
  end
```

Then I've added it to the controller with action that shows the content (page) for the iframe.
after_action :allow_iframe, only: :show_page_in_iframe

And here is the controller action itself:

```
  def show_page_in_iframe
    ...
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: 'iframe' }
    end
  end
```

Then I've deployed these changes to Production, embed the iframe with the corresponding URL to a 'localhost' page.

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/entity1/embed/66efdc3e-7cb7-436d-98e8-63275fa74ebd" height="500" width="100%" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

But in the Chrome console I can see the `Refused to display 'https://www.example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` error message.

What did I do wrong here? Is this approach still workable for Rails 6?

**Update 1.**
After some debugging in `localhost`, I've found out that the 'X-Frame-Options' value is deleted only if I have the `response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"` line precisely in the controller action. But deployment of these changes to Production (Heroku) hasn't solved the issue.

**Update 2.**
Also, I've tried to set the `ALLOWALL` value for the `X-Frame-Options` - it hasn't helped me as well.

**Update 3.**
Also, I've tried to delete the `X-Frame-Options` another way: `response.headers.except! 'X-Frame-Options'` - it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting [frame_ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)?

```
# config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb    
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.frame_ancestors :self, "*"
end
```

Comment: I don't have a specific list of permitted sites. I want to allow anyone to embed my Rails website via iFrame.

Comment: @Ivan you can try using `*` then to permit all website (Not tested, but you can give it a try)

Comment: Even if that works, how should I specify the allowed routes to be embedded?

Comment: You can have the setting inside specific controller instead of the global settings. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#content-security-policy-header