# Rails 4 X-Frame options and Facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, iframe

I have a test page  [here](http://nordicstartupawards.com/testtest/).

It seems that attempts at login into facebook from my iframed app are blocked.

```
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOW-FROM http://nordicstartupawards.com'
  }
```

as well as:

```
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
```

}

ALLOW-FROM only allows me to show the site in an iframe, ALLOWALL enables me to login from Chrome, but not Safari and Firefox. How can I set this up right so it works cross browser?

Comment: Try using the app platform URL like this: `https://apps.facebook.com/{your_app_name}`

Comment: Right, so the facebook login actually creates an iframe of its own in order to sign in and I should be whitelisting this frame instead? I tried doing   config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOW-FROM https://apps.facebook.com/588832501224049'
  } but that did not work. Not sure if it is the right url, though, as I get a message that my app is misconfigured when I visit it. Is that normal?

Comment: I'm getting an `Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://murmuring-mountain-9361.herokuapp.com/': 'ALLOW-FROM https://apps.facebook.com/588832501224049.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.` error. The `588832501224049.com` part looks strange...

Comment: Sorry, definitely a typo. I updated it, but I'm still getting an error telling that the header is invalid.

Comment: It's still there as https://apps.facebook.com/588832501224049.com

Comment: Have you seen the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573411/fix-rails-oauth-facebook-x-frame-options-sameorigin-error ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried his approach but it crashed my server when I launched it, so I suspect that the syntax was specific for an older version of Rails. Right now I am simply allowing https://apps.facebook.com but that does not work either :(